# Get device name via telnet emulated application (Delphi console), is it possible?

Tags: console-application, telnet, terminal-emulator

I have an application written in Delphi console that runs on data collectors, this application is called via telnet (terminal emulation).
Is there any way for my application to capture the name of the device that is emulating it?

Example:
The collector name that is registered in the windows registry is "DT-XXXXX"
And is written to the following windows registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ Ident \ Name

Is it possible to capture this information by an emulated application like mine?

Comment: See `TRegistry.ReadString`

Comment: It's a emulated application. TRegistry Will return server information. I need client information

Comment: I don't see any `[delphi]` flavor then, why did you tag as such?

Comment: My application is written in delphi, so when using native windows commands or windows ce and they are usually in c # or c ++. So I've specified Delphi.

Comment: This appears to be completely irrelevant to the specific question, more likely a general computing if I got your meaning of "emulated application" correct.

Comment: Is it good for you now? can you help me ?

Comment: Well, its not for me, but rather for everyone who views SO searching on the similar problem. I don't think your problem, that is, read an arbitrary remote registry key solely by the means of telnet protocol, is solvable at all. However you might want to read [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778139.aspx) and [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730627(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: It's a start, but not help me